# Is there a reason this indexOf query doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a REST API call that returns a set of data from a SharePoint list, which I've got deploying to a series of text areas.  From this, I want to take one of these text areas and test to see if a certain keyword appears in the text given.  If this returns as True, or appearing in the text, then I'm wanting a checkbox to change to checked.  This is all being done in MS Edge, and will be getting run in Edge or IE11.  Currently, none of this is happening, but I'm not getting any errors in my debugger and the REST API results are pulling normally.

```html
<textarea id="impactedAreas" style="width: 500px; height: 60px"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="custImpacted">
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="updateImpact" value="click me">
```

```js
function updateImpact(){
var impactAreas = document.getElementById("impactedAreas");
var impact = String(impactAreas);

if (impact.indexOf("Customer") >= 0 ){
document.getElementById("custImpacted").checked = true;
}
```

the text area `impactedAreas` is populated with a return of some or all of the following keywords in this format: Advisor,IT,Device,Facilities,Customer,Mobile Network,Home Network,Weather

Comment: Try with `var impact = String(impactAreas.value);`

Comment: `.getElementById()`, as the name suggests, returns an element. You want its value -> `impactAreas.value`

Comment: `String(impactAreas)` returns `"[object HTMLTextAreaElement]"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things:

1. In HTML, you need to add `()` after method name: `onclick="updateImpact()"`
2. In JS, you need to take the `.value` from `HTMLTextAreaElement` which is returned from `.getElementById()`

```js
function updateImpact(){
  var impactAreas = document.getElementById("impactedAreas");
  var impact = String(impactAreas.value); // <- here, `.value`

  if (impact.indexOf("Customer") >= 0 ){
    document.getElementById("custImpacted").checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="impactedAreas" style="width: 500px; height: 60px"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="custImpacted">
<!-- You was missing `()` after `updateImpact` -->
<input type="button" id="button" onclick="updateImpact()" value="click me">
```